# Maui BlazorHydrib Appp - x:Name attribute in .Razor pages not working

Tags: xaml, maui-blazor

Sorry for the basic question but I can't seem to find the answer.  When I create a sample project using VS 2022, it has three example pages: Counter.razor, Weather.razor, and Home.razor.  Each page has more or less the following structure:

```
@Page
```

```
//HTML goes here
```

```
@Code
```

```
//Code for HMTL goes here
```

Now, say you have a button or a label and you want to change some of it's properties. Most examples I've found, they use the x:Name attribute and then reference in the code:

```
@Page
```

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" />
```

```
@Code
```

```
MyLabel.text = "Whatever you want it to be";
```

The problem is that that particular example is always in a .xmal page that works together with a xmal.cs file where you reference the code.  Of course the .xmal page has the `<PageContent>` element where you can insert the proper links that give that functionality, but such thing is not available in the razor page (At least not that I can find it).

How can I make it work? I understand I could do something like this instead:

`@Page`

`<Label> @StringForLabel </Label>`

`@Code`

`public String StringForLabel = "Change the text this way";`

But this is incredibly annoying because I have to create variables for every single property as opposed to just mod properties on a label directly.

The other problem is that I seem to be missing some of the basic functionality.  For example:

```
<Label Text="Some text"> </Label>  //Text="Some text" does nothing.
```

I tried adding a xmal page component and do some basic test and it works, but how can it be done using .Razor pages?

I even tried doing adding the `<PageContent>` element with all of the appropriate links but it does not compile.

Thank you!

BMET1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZEA2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x:Name` does not apply to the Blazor Razor component.

For Razor components and DOM elements in Blazor apps, you can use [Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to achieve this.

Razor components provide data binding features with the [@bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bind) Razor directive attribute with a field, property, or Razor expression value.

The following example binds:

An `<input>` element value to the C# `inputValue` field.
A second `<input>` element value to the C# `InputValue` property.
When an `<input>` element loses focus, its bound field or property is updated.

`Bind.razor`

```
@page "/bind"

<PageTitle>Bind</PageTitle>

<h1>Bind Example</h1>

<p>
    <label>
        inputValue: 
        <input @bind="inputValue" />
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label>
        InputValue: 
        <input @bind="InputValue" />
    </label>
</p>

<ul>
    <li><code>inputValue</code>: @inputValue</li>
    <li><code>InputValue</code>: @InputValue</li>
</ul>

@code {
    private string? inputValue;

    private string? InputValue { get; set; }
}
```

For more information, please check document: [Binding features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#binding-features).

Comment: Thank you very much Jessie, this is the answer I was looking for.  Do you happen to know if the Text attribute is something that does not work period much like x:Name?

Say I want to create a label the old fashion way: <Label Text ="This is a test label"/>

Is this something that should work on .Razor pages?

Thanks again!

Comment: What you're talking about is MAUI or Xamarin. Form. In blazor, we can only do with [Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0).